# I am streaming binance data in python but the prices are rounded down when inserted into my mariadb db

Tags: python, pandas, mariadb, rounding, binance

I can stream the data fine and it is returning the results I want, however the data is getting rounded after a couple of decimal places when inserted into the database.

snippit of data below.

```
{
   "stream_type":"btcusdt@kline_1m",
   "event_type":"kline",
   "event_time":1686983029769,
   "symbol":"BTCUSDT",
   "kline":{
      "kline_start_time":1686982980000,
      "kline_close_time":1686983039999,
      "symbol":"BTCUSDT",
      "interval":"1m",
      "first_trade_id":false,
      "last_trade_id":false,
      "open_price":"26738.94000000",
      "close_price":"26777.99000000",
      "high_price":"26778.00000000",
      "low_price":"26738.94000000",
      "base_volume":"52.18289000",
      "number_of_trades":1613,
      "is_closed":false,
      "quote":"1396485.64284410",
      "taker_by_base_asset_volume":"37.43018000",
      "taker_by_quote_asset_volume":"1001618.64984080",
      "ignore":"0"
   },
   "unicorn_fied":[
      "binance.com",
      "0.12.2"
   ]
}
```

here is my code to retrieve the above.

here is my code to retrieve the above.

```
#import 

from unicorn_binance_websocket_api.manager import BinanceWebSocketApiManager
import time 
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#create engine to connect to DB

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://test_user:StrongPassword@127.0.0.1:3306/test_db")

#define coins to collect data from and start stream

symbols = ['BTC','COMBO']
symbols = [symbol+'usdt' for symbol in symbols]

ubwa = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com", output_default="UnicornFy")
ubwa.create_stream(['kline_1m'], symbols, output="UnicornFy")


#sort data from stream into dataframes and insert into db

def SQLimport(data):
    time = data['event_time']
    coin = data['symbol']
    open_price = data['kline']['open_price']
    close_price = data['kline']['close_price']
    low_price = data['kline']['low_price']
    high_price = data['kline']['high_price']
    volume = data['kline']['taker_by_base_asset_volume']
    frame = pd.DataFrame([[time,open_price,close_price,low_price,high_price,volume]], columns = ['time','open_price','close_price','low_price','high_price','volume'])
    frame.time = pd.to_datetime(frame.time, unit='ms')
    frame.open_price = frame.open_price.astype(float)
    frame.close_price = frame.close_price.astype(float)
    frame.low_price = frame.low_price.astype(float)
    frame.high_price = frame.high_price.astype(float)
    frame.volume = frame.volume.astype(float)
    frame['amplitude'] = (frame.high_price - frame.low_price) / (frame.high_price     + frame.low_price) /2
    frame.to_sql(coin, engine, index=False, if_exists='append')

while True:
    data = ubwa.pop_stream_data_from_stream_buffer()

    if data:
        if len(data) > 3:
            SQLimport(data)
            print(data)
```

This imports the data into the db and also prints it out on the screen, however the values printed show the full prices eg (26738.94000000), where if this record is returned from the db it would show 26738.94, it seems to be rounding the prices or not inserting them fully.  I have manually inserted data and it will accept it fine but through my script, the open, close, high and low columns are rounded to 2 decimal places.

I also setup a sqlite db and inserted the data there too and had the same results.

I have googled all night, read the pandas docs as best as I can and am stumped.

am I missing somthing obvious ?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: How did you define the database column for price?

Comment: the datatype is Double, the tables and columns were created with the script.

Comment: -- test_db.BTCUSDT definition

    CREATE TABLE `BTCUSDT` (
      `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `open_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `close_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `low_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `high_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `volume` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `amplitude` double DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

Comment: 26738.94000000 = 26738.94. Where do you see rounding? Also the preferred datatype would be decimal instead of double.

Comment: I appreciate your response, I had to look at the data and you were correct (I was wrong and saw the whole data being printed, but as you said anything after. The 94 was just unneeded zeros, my head was in the wrong place.) I check multiple records with different data sets and again as you said the zeros didn't matter.  Sorry for wasting your time, I was too engrossed and didn't see the obvious.

Comment: Also I agree and storing as decimal would be what I would have preferred, but the code I had auto created the tables with double as the dataset and not decimal.